# Exoplayer 2 change media source to clip video

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to implement exoplayer 2 for one of our applications.

Seems like the documentation and examples for something more complicated than automatic playback is very poor.

My problem is I create a mediasource and set it to the player, after that I have a custom icon that plays the video and on finish I seek back to 0.

Also I have a custom dual seekbar that when moved it will seek to a position and clip the video between the selected start and end time.

I am not sure if changing source of the player without recreating the whole thing is even possible.

I init my player as:

```
@AfterViews
protected void init() {
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
        mPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getContext(), trackSelector);
        mVideoView.setPlayer(mPlayer);
        mPlayer.addListener(this);
}
```

After that I prepare the player like this:

```
public void setVideoPath(final String videoPath) {
        mVideoPath = videoPath;
        // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getContext(), Util.getUserAgent(getContext(), "yourApplicationName"));
        // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
        videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoPath));
        mPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
}
```

When my play icon is clicked it runs:

```
@Click(R.id.view_video_preview_container_play)
    void onPlayClicked() {
        mPlayButton.setVisibility(GONE);
        mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```

When the playback is finished I do:

```
@Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

        if (playbackState == STATE_ENDED) {
            mPlayButton.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            mPlayer.seekTo(0);
            mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        }
}
```

No when I seek I do:

```
disposable = source
                .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(range -> {
                            mPlayer.stop();
                            mPlayButton.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                            clippingSource = new ClippingMediaSource(videoSource, 2000000, 5000000);
                            mPlayer.prepare(clippingSource);
                        }
                );
```

Now when the source emits to my observable I get back:

```
2018-11-16 12:48:16.463 28090-28209/nl.dtt.vormats E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ClippingMediaSource$IllegalClippingException: Illegal clipping: not seekable to start
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ClippingMediaSource$ClippingTimeline.<init>(ClippingMediaSource.java:350)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ClippingMediaSource.refreshClippedTimeline(ClippingMediaSource.java:296)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ClippingMediaSource.onChildSourceInfoRefreshed(ClippingMediaSource.java:262)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ClippingMediaSource.onChildSourceInfoRefreshed(ClippingMediaSource.java:34)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.CompositeMediaSource$1.onSourceInfoRefreshed(CompositeMediaSource.java:103)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BaseMediaSource.refreshSourceInfo(BaseMediaSource.java:73)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource.notifySourceInfoRefreshed(ExtractorMediaSource.java:400)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource.prepareSourceInternal(ExtractorMediaSource.java:348)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BaseMediaSource.prepareSource(BaseMediaSource.java:137)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.CompositeMediaSource.prepareChildSource(CompositeMediaSource.java:109)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ClippingMediaSource.prepareSourceInternal(ClippingMediaSource.java:216)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BaseMediaSource.prepareSource(BaseMediaSource.java:137)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.prepareInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:396)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:286)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Unfortunately as I stated before the documentation if very poor and I managed only to find out that the exceptions is thrown at:

```
if (startUs != 0 && !window.isSeekable) {
          throw new IllegalClippingException(IllegalClippingException.REASON_NOT_SEEKABLE_TO_START);
}
```

Specifically window.isSeekable is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to recreate the the MediaSource as it seems like the same MediaSource can not be reused.